# Getting blank response in the javascript file while fetching the API response

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, api

[image]I have a button. When I click that button, Login method in the js file gets executed. Inside the Login method, I am calling an API. I am trying to fetch the output returned by the API  but I am getting blank response in the alert message in the below code.
I am getting the correct response when trying to hit the API through Postman.
Here is the js code where I am calling the API-

```
function Login() {
    
    var url="https://localhost:44369/categories?username="+"sid"+"&password="+"123";
   

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    
  }
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.send(null);
}
```

Here is the get API code-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace login.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("categories")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(string username,string password)
        {
            loginResponse response = new loginResponse();
            if(username=="sid" && password== "123"){

                response.Success = true;
            }
            else
            {
                response.Success = false;
            }
            return Ok(response);

        }

       
        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use your browser's Developer Tools (network and console tools) to inspect what is happening?

Comment: Yes, I put a debugger in the js file. Everything is working fine, but this - "xhr.responseText" is coming blank
No error in the console and the network is showing the API call when I click the button

Comment: Try specifying the response type as JSON i.e. `xhr.responseType = 'json';` before you send your request. You can then get the response object i.e. `let responseObj = xhr.response` and then `alert (responseObj.message)`; Postman is showing a JSON response type. Reference link https://javascript.info/xmlhttprequest#response-type

Comment: If you examine the network call and look at the raw response in the tab, is the correct result showing there?

Comment: var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType='json';
 xhr.send();
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

        let responseObj = xhr.response;
        window.alert("Hello");
    window.alert(responseObj.message);
    I ran this code
The debugger is not to the window.alert code
Its going here - "let responseObj = xhr.response;" and then comes out without showing any window alert

Comment: Ok. That wasn't what I asked you to check.

Comment: @ADysonI am getting "Failed to load response data" in Preview and Response
Also, the Status is being shown as cancelled in the Network tab in chrome

Comment: What is the status code of the response? It sounds like maybe you have a network or connection error

Comment: After I removed the form element in the html code, now I am getting the Status as "pending" which was earlier "cancelled"

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me -

```
var username=document.getElementById("UserName").value;
var password=document.getElementById("Password").value;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://localhost:44369/categories?username=sid&password=12', true);
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    console.log(xhr);
    if (xhr.readyState=== 4) {
        console.log(xhr.response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you confused you can create code for JavaScript XHR in Postman, follow below steps:

[image]

[image]

I think below code works:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  if(this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://localhost:44369/categories?username=sid&password=123");

xhr.send();
```

Comment: I have used the same  code that you have mentioned
If I am keeping the readyState as 1, then its going inside the if statement and giving  blank output. So basically, the problem is that instead of 4, I am getting readyState as 1

Comment: readyState 1 means your request opened, you should wait until readyState 4 because it means request done, check this link to understand what i talking about:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState